# how to pass option id or text value in php

Tags: php, html

i want to get option id value in php

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity" tabindex="2" onchange="calculate(this)" required autofocus>
    <option value="">Choose Your Quantity</option>
    <?php
    if($prodqty) {
        foreach($prodqty as $qty) {
            for($i = $qty->quantity_from; $i <= $qty->quantity_to; $i++) {
    ?>
            <option value="<?=$qty->discount?>" id="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>

     <?php } } } ?>
     </select>
```

I want to pass `$i` value that is placed in option id and also between option tag in php. i prefer to send this value through php

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: If you want to send this to another page, you have to use either ajax or html form.

Comment: when the option get selected then assign that id to some hidden field using javascript,and after submitting the form in post `$_POST['hidden field name']` you'll get the value

Comment: Sir. There is HTML in you PHP.... Google: PHP Templating